# react-google-autocomplete options not working

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api, react-google-autocomplete

I am using react-google-autocomplete with react-hook-form:
And when I try to add options parameters to the Component (which should filter my API predictions down to **my country, and only cities**, but it's clearly not working:

```
  const { register, handleSubmit , control} = useForm();

          <Controller
        name="location"
        rules={{
          required: "This is a required field"
        }}
        control={control}
        render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
          <PlaceAutoComplete
            {...field}
            error={fieldState.error}
          />
        )}
      />
```

And the autocomplete component:

```
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from "react-google-places-autocomplete";

export const PlaceAutoComplete = ({ error, ...field }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        apiKey="APIKEY"
        apiOptions={{
          types: ["(cities)"],
          componentRestrictions: { country: "hu" },
        }}
        selectProps={{
          ...field,
          isClearable: true,
        }}
      />
      {error && <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{error.message}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlaceAutoComplete;
```

When I check the network log, you can see no options added to the query:
Request URL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictionsJson?1sLondon&4shu-HU&15e3&21m1&2e1&callback=_xdc_._dpoln7&key=APIKEY&token=111550`

When I try to search for London, there should be no option, because I restrict to 'hu'- Hungary and only city:

[image: wrong_prediction]